# Google Maps API Zoom into specfic regions

Tags: javascript, api, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I am trying to make the Google Maps API respond to an elementclick and zoom into a specific region.

For example. The Map is showing the entire United States, and I click Arizona, I want the map to zoom in the entire state of Arizona. Then I can either hit clear and have the map reset or click another state, say Florida. And have it zoom there.

Additionally, this needs to a global solution. I have regions in Europe, Germany, Russia, Australia I want to add this functionality too.

Thank you for your time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can define the coordinates and use the zoom level then center your map in that coordinate.

Consider this script.

```
var zoomLevel = 18; //The higher the zoomLevel means zoom in at a higher resolution
var map;

var arizonaCoor = new google.maps.LatLng(39.739318, -89.266507);
var otherCoor = new google.maps.LatLng(49.733418, -30.234507);
var origCoor = new google.maps.LatLng(39.739318, -89.266507);

var mapOptions = {
center: origCoor,
zoom: 5,
mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
};
map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map_canvas'),
            mapOptions);


function onArizonaClick(){
    map.setCenter(arizonaCoor, zoomLevel);

}
function onClear(){
    map.setCenter(origCoor, 5);
}
```

Answer (score 5):

You can use the Google Maps API v3 geocoding service to zoom to the viewport it returns for [states](http://geocodezip.com/v3_zoom2stateSelectList.html) and [countries](http://geocodezip.com/v3_zoom2countrySelectList.html)

**code snippet (zoom to US states)**

```js
var map = null;
var geocoder = null;

function initialize() {
  geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();
  var myOptions = {
    zoom: 2,
    center: new google.maps.LatLng(47.288828765662416, 7.945261001586914),
    mapTypeControl: true,
    mapTypeControlOptions: {
      style: google.maps.MapTypeControlStyle.DROPDOWN_MENU
    },
    navigationControl: true,
    mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
  };
  map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map_canvas"), myOptions);
  findAddress("United States");
}

function findAddress(address) {
  var addressStr = document.getElementById("stateselect").value;
  if (!address && (addressStr != ''))
    address = "State of " + addressStr;
  else
    address = addressStr;
  if ((address != '') && geocoder) {
    geocoder.geocode({
      'address': address
    }, function(results, status) {
      if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {
        if (status != google.maps.GeocoderStatus.ZERO_RESULTS) {
          if (results && results[0] &&
            results[0].geometry && results[0].geometry.viewport)
            map.fitBounds(results[0].geometry.viewport);
        } else {
          alert("No results found");
        }
      } else {
        alert("Geocode was not successful for the following reason: " + status);
      }
    });
  }
}
initialize();
```

```css
html,
body {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  padding: 0px;
  margin: 0px;
}

#map_canvas {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyCkUOdZ5y7hMm0yrcCQoCvLwzdM6M8s5qk"></script>
<h2>Zoom to State with Select List (Google Maps API)</h2>
<div id="TOPNAV">
  <select id="stateselect" name="countryselect" class="textfeld" onclick="findAddress();return false" onchange="findAddress();return false" onfocus="">
    <option value=''>Select a State....</option>
    <option value="Alabama">Alabama</option>
    <option value="Alaska">Alaska</option>
    <option value="Arizona">Arizona</option>
    <option value="Arkansas">Arkansas</option>
    <option value="California">California</option>
    <option value="Colorado">Colorado</option>
    <option value="Connecticut">Connecticut</option>
    <option value="Delaware">Delaware</option>
    <option value="Florida">Florida</option>
    <option value="Georgia">Georgia</option>
    <option value="Hawaii">Hawaii</option>
    <option value="Idaho">Idaho</option>
    <option value="Illinois">Illinois</option>
    <option value="Indiana">Indiana</option>
    <option value="Iowa">Iowa</option>
    <option value="Kansas">Kansas</option>
    <option value="Kentucky">Kentucky</option>
    <option value="Louisiana">Louisiana</option>
    <option value="Maine">Maine</option>
    <option value="Maryland">Maryland</option>
    <option value="Massachusetts">Massachusetts</option>
    <option value="Michigan">Michigan</option>
    <option value="Minnesota">Minnesota</option>
    <option value="Mississippi">Mississippi</option>
    <option value="Missouri">Missouri</option>
    <option value="Montana">Montana</option>
    <option value="Nebraska">Nebraska</option>
    <option value="Nevada">Nevada</option>
    <option value="New Hampshire">New Hampshire</option>
    <option value="New Jersey">New Jersey</option>
    <option value="New Mexico">New Mexico</option>
    <option value="New York">New York</option>
    <option value="North Carolina">North Carolina</option>
    <option value="North Dakota">North Dakota</option>
    <option value="Ohio">Ohio</option>
    <option value="Oklahoma">Oklahoma</option>
    <option value="Oregon">Oregon</option>
    <option value="Pennsylvania">Pennsylvania</option>
    <option value="Rhode Island">Rhode Island</option>
    <option value="South Carolina">South Carolina</option>
    <option value="South Dakota">South Dakota</option>
    <option value="Tennessee">Tennessee</option>
    <option value="Texas">Texas</option>
    <option value="Utah">Utah</option>
    <option value="Vermont">Vermont</option>
    <option value="Virginia">Virginia</option>
    <option value="Washington">Washington</option>
    <option value="West Virginia">West Virginia</option>
    <option value="Wisconsin">Wisconsin</option>
    <option value="Wyoming">Wyoming</option>
  </select>
</div>
<div id="map_canvas" style="width: 800px; height: 500px"></div>
```

**code snippet (zoom to country)**

```js
// globals
var map = null;
var geocoder = null;

function initialize() {
  geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();
  var myOptions = {
    zoom: 2,
    center: new google.maps.LatLng(47.288828765662416, 7.945261001586914),
    mapTypeControl: true,
    mapTypeControlOptions: {
      style: google.maps.MapTypeControlStyle.DROPDOWN_MENU
    },
    navigationControl: true,
    mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
  };
  map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map_canvas"), myOptions);
}

function findAddress(address) {
  if (!address)
    var address = document.getElementById("countryselect").value;
  if ((address != '') && geocoder) {
    geocoder.geocode({
      'address': address
    }, function(results, status) {
      google.maps.event.addListenerOnce(map, 'center_changed', centerChanged);
      google.maps.event.addListenerOnce(map, 'bounds_changed', centerChanged);
      if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {
        if (status != google.maps.GeocoderStatus.ZERO_RESULTS) {
          if ((results && results[0] && results[0].formatted_address) && (results[0].formatted_address == "Antarctica")) {
            map.setCenter(new google.maps.LatLng(-75, 0));
            map.setZoom(3);
          } else if (results && results[0] && results[0].geometry && results[0].geometry.viewport) {
            map.fitBounds(results[0].geometry.viewport);
            var htmlStr = results[0].formatted_address + "<br>";
            htmlStr += "viewport=" + results[0].geometry.viewport.toUrlValue(6) + "<br>";
            htmlStr += "bounds=" + results[0].geometry.bounds.toUrlValue(6) + "<br>";
            document.getElementById('info').innerHTML = htmlStr;
          } else if (results && results[0] && results[0].geometry && results[0].geometry.bounds) {
            map.fitBounds(results[0].geometry.bounds);
            var htmlStr = results[0].formatted_address + "<br>";
            htmlStr += "bounds=" + results[0].geometry.bounds.toUrlValue(6) + "<br>";
            document.getElementById('info').innerHTML = htmlStr;
          } else {
            var htmlStr = results[0].formatted_address + "" < br > "";
            document.getElementById('info').innerHTML = htmlStr;
          }
        } else {
          alert("No results found");
        }
      } else {
        alert("Geocode was not successful for the following reason: " + status);
      }
    });
  }
}

function centerChanged() {
  document.getElementById('info').innerHTML += "<br>center=" + map.getCenter().toUrlValue(6) + "<br>map.getBounds=" + map.getBounds().toUrlValue(6);
  google.maps.event.addListenerOnce(map, 'center_changed', function() {
    document.getElementById('info').innerHTML += "<br>center=" + map.getCenter().toUrlValue(6) + "<br>map.getBounds=" + map.getBounds().toUrlValue(6);
  });
  if (map.getCenter().lat() < -85) {
    google.maps.event.addListenerOnce(map, 'center_changed', function() {
      map.setZoom(3);
    });
    map.setCenter(new google.maps.LatLng(-75, 0));
  } else if (map.getCenter().lat() > 85) {
    google.maps.event.addListenerOnce(map, 'center_changed', function() {
      map.setZoom(3);
    });
    map.setCenter(new google.maps.LatLng(75, 0));
  }
}
initialize();
```

```css
html,
body {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  padding: 0px;
  margin: 0px;
}

#map_canvas {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyCkUOdZ5y7hMm0yrcCQoCvLwzdM6M8s5qk"></script>
<h2>Zoom to Country with Select List (Google Maps API)</h2>
<div id="TOPNAV">
  <select id="countryselect" name="countryselect" class="textfeld" onclick="findAddress();return false" onchange="findAddress();return false" onfocus="">
    <option value=''>Select a country....</option>
    <option value="Afghanistan">Afghanistan</option>
    <option value="Albania">Albania</option>
    <option value="Algeria">Algeria</option>
    <option value="American Samoa">American Samoa</option>
    <option value="Andorra">Andorra</option>
    <option value="Angola">Angola</option>
    <option value="Anguilla">Anguilla</option>
    <option value="Antarctica">Antarctica</option>
    <option value="Antigua and Barbuda">Antigua and Barbuda</option>
    <option value="Argentina">Argentina</option>
    <option value="Armenia">Armenia</option>
    <option value="Aruba">Aruba</option>
    <option value="Australia">Australia</option>
    <option value="Austria">Austria</option>
    <option value="Azerbaijan">Azerbaijan</option>
    <option value="Bahamas">Bahamas</option>
    <option value="Bahrain">Bahrain</option>
    <option value="Bangladesh">Bangladesh</option>
    <option value="Barbados">Barbados</option>
    <option value="Belarus">Belarus</option>
    <option value="Belgium">Belgium</option>
    <option value="Belize">Belize</option>
    <option value="Benin">Benin</option>
    <option value="Bermuda">Bermuda</option>
    <option value="Bhutan">Bhutan</option>
    <option value="Bolivia">Bolivia</option>
    <option value="Bosnia and Herzegovina">Bosnia and Herzegovina</option>
    <option value="Botswana">Botswana</option>
    <option value="Bouvet Island">Bouvet Island</option>
    <option value="Brazil">Brazil</option>
    <option value="British Indian Ocean Territory">British Indian Ocean Territory</option>
    <option value="Brunei Darussalam">Brunei Darussalam</option>
    <option value="Bulgaria">Bulgaria</option>
    <option value="Burkina Faso">Burkina Faso</option>
    <option value="Burundi">Burundi</option>
    <option value="Cambodia">Cambodia</option>
    <option value="Cameroon">Cameroon</option>
    <option value="Canada">Canada</option>
    <option value="Cape Verde">Cape Verde</option>
    <option value="Cayman Islands">Cayman Islands</option>
    <option value="Central African Republic">Central African Republic</option>
    <option value="Chad">Chad</option>
    <option value="Chile">Chile</option>
    <option value="China">China</option>
    <option value="Christmas Island">Christmas Island</option>
    <option value="Cocos (Keeling) Islands">Cocos (Keeling) Islands</option>
    <option value="Colombia">Colombia</option>
    <option value="Comoros">Comoros</option>
    <option value="Congo">Congo</option>
    <option value="Democratic Republic of the Congo">Congo, the Democratic Republic of the</option>
    <option value="Cook Islands">Cook Islands</option>
    <option value="Costa Rica">Costa Rica</option>
    <option value="Cote D'Ivoire">Cote D'Ivoire</option>
    <option value="Croatia">Croatia</option>
    <option value="Cuba">Cuba</option>
    <option value="Cyprus">Cyprus</option>
    <option value="Czech Republic">Czech Republic</option>
    <option value="Denmark">Denmark</option>
    <option value="Djibouti">Djibouti</option>
    <option value="Dominica">Dominica</option>
    <option value="Dominican Republic">Dominican Republic</option>
    <option value="Ecuador">Ecuador</option>
    <option value="Egypt">Egypt</option>
    <option value="El Salvador">El Salvador</option>
    <option value="Equatorial Guinea">Equatorial Guinea</option>
    <option value="Eritrea">Eritrea</option>
    <option value="Estonia">Estonia</option>
    <option value="Ethiopia">Ethiopia</option>
    <option value="Falkland Islands (Malvinas)">Falkland Islands (Malvinas)</option>
    <option value="Faroe Islands">Faroe Islands</option>
    <option value="Fiji">Fiji</option>
    <option value="Finland">Finland</option>
    <option value="France">France</option>
    <option value="French Guiana">French Guiana</option>
    <option value="French Polynesia">French Polynesia</option>
    <option value="French Southern Territories">French Southern Territories</option>
    <option value="Gabon">Gabon</option>
    <option value="Gambia">Gambia</option>
    <option value="Georgia Country">Georgia</option>
    <option value="Germany">Germany</option>
    <option value="Ghana">Ghana</option>
    <option value="Gibraltar">Gibraltar</option>
    <option value="Greece">Greece</option>
    <option value="Greenland">Greenland</option>
    <option value="Grenada">Grenada</option>
    <option value="Guadeloupe">Guadeloupe</option>
    <option value="Guam">Guam</option>
    <option value="Guatemala">Guatemala</option>
    <option value="Guinea">Guinea</option>
    <optio n value="Guinea-Bissau">Guinea-Bissau</option>
      <option value="Guyana">Guyana</option>
      <option value="Haiti">Haiti</option>
      <option value="Heard Island and Mcdonald Islands">Heard Island and Mcdonald Islands</option>
      <option value="Vatican City State">Holy See (Vatican City State)</option>
      <option value="Honduras">Honduras</option>
      <option value="Hong Kong">Hong Kong</option>
      <option value="Hungary">Hungary</option>
      <option value="Iceland">Iceland</option>
      <option value="India">India</option>
      <option value="Indonesia">Indonesia</option>
      <option value="Iran Country">Iran, Islamic Republic of</option>
      <option value="Iraq">Iraq</option>
      <option value="Ireland">Ireland</option>
      <option value="Israel">Israel</option>
      <option value="Italy">Italy</option>
      <option value="Jamaica">Jamaica</option>
      <option value="Japan">Japan</option>
      <option value="Jordan">Jordan</option>
      <option value="Kazakhstan">Kazakhstan</option>
      <option value="Kenya">Kenya</option>
      <option value="Kiribati">Kiribati</option>
      <option value="North Korea">Korea, North</option>
      <option value="South Korea">Korea, South</option>
      <option value="Kuwait">Kuwait</option>
      <option value="Kyrgyzstan">Kyrgyzstan</option>
      <option value="Lao People's Democratic Republic">Lao People's Democratic Republic</option>
      <option value="Latvia">Latvia</option>
      <option value="Lebanon">Lebanon</option>
      <option value="Lesotho">Lesotho</option>
      <option value="Liberia">Liberia</option>
      <option value="Libyan Arab Jamahiriya">Libyan Arab Jamahiriya</option>
      <option value="Liechtenstein">Liechtenstein</option>
      <option value="Lithuania">Lithuania</option>
      <option value="Luxembourg">Luxembourg</option>
      <option value="Macao Country">Macao</option>
      <option value="Macedonia">Macedonia, the Former Yugoslav Republic of</option>
      <option value="Madagascar">Madagascar</option>
      <option value="Malawi">Malawi</option>
      <option value="Malaysia">Malaysia</option>
      <option value="Maldives">Maldives</option>
      <option value="Mali">Mali</option>
      <option value="Malta">Malta</option>
      <option value="Marshall Islands">Marshall Islands</option>
      <option value="Martinique">Martinique</option>
      <option value="Mauritania">Mauritania</option>
      <option value="Mauritius">Mauritius</option>
      <option value="Mayotte">Mayotte</option>
      <option value="Mexico">Mexico</option>
      <option value="Federated States of Micronesia">Micronesia, Federated States of</option>
      <option value="Moldova">Moldova, Republic of</option>
      <option value="Monaco">Monaco</option>
      <option value="Mongolia">Mongolia</option>
      <option value="Montserrat">Montserrat</option>
      <option value="Montenegro">Montenegro</option>
      <option value="Morocco">Morocco</option>
      <option value="Mozambique">Mozambique</option>
      <option value="Myanmar">Myanmar</option>
      <option value="Namibia">Namibia</option>
      <option value="Nauru">Nauru</option>
      <option value="Nepal">Nepal</option>
      <option value="Netherlands">Netherlands</option>
      <option value="Netherlands Antilles">Netherlands Antilles</option>
      <option value="New Caledonia">New Caledonia</option>
      <option value="New Zealand">New Zealand</option>
      <option value="Nicaragua">Nicaragua</option>
      <option value="Niger">Niger</option>
      <option value="Nigeria">Nigeria</option>
      <option value="Niue">Niue</option>
      <option value="Norfolk Island">Norfolk Island</option>
      <option value="Northern Mariana Islands">Northern Mariana Islands</option>
      <option value="Norway">Norway</option>
      <option value="Oman">Oman</option>
      <option value="Pakistan">Pakistan</option>
      <option value="Palau">Palau</option>
      <option value="Palestine">Palestine</option>
      <option value="Panama">Panama</option>
      <option value="Papua New Guinea">Papua New Guinea</option>
      <option value="Paraguay">Paraguay</option>
      <option value="Peru">Peru</option>
      <option value="Philippines">Philippines</option>
      <option value="Pitcairn">Pitcairn</option>
      <option value="Poland">Poland</option>
      <option value="Portugal">Portugal</option>
      <option value="Puerto Rico">Puerto Rico</option>
      <option value="Qatar">Qatar</option>
      <option value="Reunion">Reunion</option>
      <option value="Romania">Romania</option>
      <option value="Russian Federation">Russian Federation</option>
      <option value="Rwanda">Rwanda</option>
      <option value="Saint Helena Country">Saint Helena</option>
      <option value="Saint Kitts and Nevis">Saint Kitts and Nevis</option>
      <option value="Saint Lucia">Saint Lucia</option>
      <option value="Saint Pierre and Miquelon">Saint Pierre and Miquelon</option>
      <option value="Saint Vincent and the Grenadines">Saint Vincent and the Grenadines</option>
      <option value="Samoa">Samoa</option>
      <option value="San Marino">San Marino</option>
      <option value="Sao Tome and Principe">Sao Tome and Principe</option>
      <option value="Saudi Arabia">Saudi Arabia</option>
      <option value="Senegal">Senegal</option>
      <option value="Serbia">Serbia</option>
      <option value="Seychelles">Seychelles</option>
      <option value="Sierra Leone">Sierra Leone</option>
      <option value="Singapore">Singapore</option>
      <option value="Slovakia">Slovakia</option>
      <option value="Slovenia">Slovenia</option>
      <option value="Solomon Islands">Solomon Islands</option>
      <option value="Somalia">Somalia</option>
      <option value="South Africa">South Africa</option>
      <option value="South Georgia and the South Sandwich Islands">South Georgia and the South Sandwich Islands</option>
      <option value="Spain">Spain</option>
      <option value="Sri Lanka">Sri Lanka</option>
      <option value="Sudan">Sudan</option>
      <option value="Suriname">Suriname</option>
      <option value="Svalbard and Jan Mayen">Svalbard and Jan Mayen</option>
      <option value="Swaziland">Swaziland</option>
      <option value="Sweden">Sweden</option>
      <option value="Switzerland">Switzerland</option>
      <option value="Syrian Arab Republic">Syrian Arab Republic</option>
      <option value="Taiwan">Taiwan, Province of China</option>
      <option value="Tajikistan">Tajikistan</option>
      <option value="Tanzania">Tanzania, United Republic of</option>
      <option value="Thailand">Thailand</option>
      <option value="Timor-Leste">Timor-Leste</option>
      <option value="Togo">Togo</option>
      <option value="Tokelau">Tokelau</option>
      <option value="Tonga">Tonga</option>
      <option value="Trinidad and Tobago">Trinidad and Tobago</option>
      <option value="Tunisia">Tunisia</option>
      <option value="Turkey">Turkey</option>
      <option value="Turkmenistan">Turkmenistan</option>
      <option value="Turks and Caicos Islands">Turks and Caicos Islands</option>
      <option value="Tuvalu">Tuvalu</option>
      <option value="Uganda">Uganda</option>
      <option value="Ukraine">Ukraine</option>
      <option value="United Arab Emirates">United Arab Emirates</option>
      <option value="United Kingdom">United Kingdom</option>
      <option value="United States">United States</option>
      <!-- <option value="United States Minor Outlying Islands">United States Minor Outlying Islands</option> -->
      <option value="Uruguay">Uruguay</option>
      <option value="Uzbekistan">Uzbekistan</option>
      <option value="Vanuatu">Vanuatu</option>
      <option value="Venezuela">Venezuela</option>
      <option value="Viet Nam">Viet Nam</option>
      <option value="British Virgin Islands">Virgin Islands, British</option>
      <option value="U.S. Virgin Islands">Virgin Islands, U.S.</option>
      <option value="Wallis and Futuna">Wallis and Futuna</option>
      <option value="Western Sahara">Western Sahara</option>
      <option value="Yemen">Yemen</option>
      <option value="Zambia">Zambia</option>
      <option value="Zimbabwe">Zimbabwe</option>
  </select>
</div>
<div id="map_canvas" style="width: 800px; height: 500px"></div>
<div id="info"></div>
```

Comment: thx for your answer. do you know if there is there a way to zoom in to get smaller regions within those particular states?

Comment: If you know their names.